# Get value from Excel based on find result

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a list of products in A column and for every product its price is written in B column.

Now i want to  search for any product and if found in A column then it simply copy the price value of a product from B column.

Below is the code to find the product but I don't know how to copy the price value.

```
  $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
  $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\Raj\Desktop\Book1.xlsx')
  $workSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
  $WorkSheet.Name
  $Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find('pencil')

  If ($Found.)
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: If you haven't seen DougFinke's ImportExcel yet you may want to see if this does what you are looking for with the cmdlets in that module: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($Found){
    $price = $workSheet.Cells($Found.row,2).Value2
}else{
    Write-Host "not found"
}
```

This isn't the optimal way to deal with a lookup in an Excel sheet. It's open to problems - e.g. what if the item is listed more than once? I would recommend having a think about storing the data as CSV that's much easier to import into PowerShell, or figuring out how to import from the xlsx into csv.

Comment: sir , You are superbbbb

Comment: $price is  showing the item price which is correct but i want in function to copy the item price value. Simply i dnt want to store in a variable i want in function to copy the price value. please help

Comment: Copy it to where? The variable stores the price value... you can then paste it where it needs to go.

Comment: i figured it out, tq you for ur support. appreciate ur help